# jquery .closest() select itself when trying to access the closest upper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Actually What I want is to hide the immediate upper div of an div element if it is empty

So I written the code like this

```
if ($.trim($('#searchQuery').html()) == '') {

    $('#searchQuery').closest("div").css("display", "none");
}
```

The element with the `id searchQuery` is itself is `div` so what it is doing it is hiding itself.

Anybody know what to do in this case why its behavior is like this??

Comment: @all Anybody who can explain why it is happening like this??? It should select the upper one.

Comment: Check my answer for other possible improvements to the rest of your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20971708/491044

Comment: Check DOC, closest include element itself. Equivalent without including element itself would be `.parents('div').first()` But if you want immediate parent (if a DIV), why not using `parent('div')` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Jquery [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) documentation.

**Jquery .closest()**

For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the **element itself** and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
1 .Begins with the current element
```

Your selector `[.closest("div")]` refers the current element `#searchQuery`

```
2. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
```

`#searchQuery` is the first element in DOM tree, which perfectly matched with the current selector  `[.closest("div")]`

**Updated:**

Here you can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector instead of using `.closest()`.

Or you can use  `.closest()` selector with [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- Use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to avoid getting HTML tags which wont be removed in the trim.
- Use `.hide()` instead of `.css("display", "none")`.
- Use `.parent()` for immediate parent.

Example solution:

```
$('#searchQuery').parent().hide();
```

- More info on [jQuery .parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- More info on [jQuery .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: But parent() just check for one level ancestor. PS: sorry didn't saw that: `to hide the immediate upper div`   +1

Comment: He wanted the immediate parent. Of course you can filter too as in your comment. I included a link to the docs.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work if the div isn't the immediate parent.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use `:not(..)`.

```
$('#searchQuery').closest("div:not(#searchQuery)").hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

It selects itself because it

> Begins with the current element

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Or you could use `.parents(...)` (note the `s` on the end). This travels trough the DOM tree until it finds the selector you pass in the argument.

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply this ?

```
$('#searchQuery').parent("div").css("display", "none");
```

As an aside, as trgraglia noticed, you shoud also use `hide` :

```
$('#searchQuery').parent("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by "upper div"

If it's the previous sibling:

```
$('#searchQuery').prev().css("display", "none");
```

or the parent:

```
$('#searchQuery').parent().css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Indeed, or set a CSS class of "hidden" which can then be toggled

Answer (score 1):

Use .parent() instead of closest :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same issue today and solved it by doing :

```
$myelement.parent().closest('div');
```

this will ignore $myelement and look above it